# Installing only ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up Ruby on Rails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails)

It seems that if I do an "sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential" the Ruby is installed with version 1.8.

How can I install *only* version 1.9?