# Step by step guide to install Ruby on Rails?

Tags: installation, rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up Ruby on Rails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails)

Can anybody give me a step by step guide to installing ruby on rails 3 with mysql2 on Ubuntu 10.04 (assuming I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04).

Comment: Here's information for 10.10 which might be useful to you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Is there really that big a difference between installing on 10.04 and 10.10? http://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I'm guessing you mean mysql 5 - mysql 2 is very old now.

Comment: the mysql2 package is what he means, that's how the gem is labeled