# How can I easily install ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, rails, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up Ruby on Rails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails)

How can I easily install RVM, ruby 1.9.3, rubygems, passenger and rails all in one go ?

Comment: Possible duplicates - http://askubuntu.com/questions/48984/best-way-to-install-ruby-1-9-rails-3-postgres-heroku-github-using-rvm - http://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails - http://askubuntu.com/questions/13541/step-by-step-guide-to-install-ruby-on-rails

Comment: However, if you could [join me in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room), we can talk about how to make this one the "master" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this script to do all that in one line:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/joshfng/railsready/master/railsready.sh && bash railsready.sh
```

At the end, just log out and in from the terminal window (no need to reboot the OS).

So at the $ sign type `exit`

then start the window up (or start a new remote session that gets you to the `$` sign =, i.e. "command line access" (CLI) the same way you did before and log in again.

Comment: sure but 'terminal window' is really common everywhere I've been

Comment: I added more info, I really think logging out and in are basic and if folks don't understand those terms they have some other knowledge needs perhaps they should learn first.  They're here because they're using a pc.

Comment: I wasn't saying I thought you needed to explain how to log out. I was saying I thought the term "log out and in from the terminal window" is confusing. I think if you just replaced it with "log out and back in" (and even removed the new thing about `exit`) it would be fine. But it's your call.

Comment: No problem.  What I was really alluding to was the fact that you 'only' logged' out from the terminal window.  A lot of folks might think log out of the pc and back in, so this was meant to emphasize just the terminal window.