# Best way to Install Ruby 1.9, Rails 3, Postgres, Heroku, GitHub, Using RVM?

Tags: ruby, rails, rvm, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set up Ruby on Rails?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7654/how-do-i-set-up-ruby-on-rails)

Best way to Install RUBY 1.9, Rails 3, Postgres, Heroku, GitHub, Using RVM

Can anyone suggest me the way in which should I follow to install it properly, because previously I felt in various dependencies issues.

Suggest something It's urgent !!!