# Installing Ruby On Rails stack on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, ruby, rails, rvm

I'm looking to install ruby on rails on Ubuntu similarly to how its described in the RailsIntaller.org for MAC/Windows. Instructions and guides that I've seen to do this on Ubuntu seem to be all over the place and everyone seems to have their own way as to how to do this. I'm a Ubuntu newbie and would like this as simple as possible if it can be done. Does anyone have a guide/video/tutorial they recommend?. What rubyinstaller.org download installs it? And what I would like to get installed as well is:

- Ruby
- Rails
- Bundler
- Git
- Sqlite
- Tiny TDS/OSX GCC installer/ Ubuntu equivalent
- Jewelry Box
- RVM
- SM framework

Comment: This is pretty much an exact duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/7654/7808. Adding another question isn't going to help with the problem of instructions and guides to do this on Ubuntu being all over the place :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is repeated question but simply you can follow these post that make your installation hassle free:

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/15.10 -- **Latest and usefull blog**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/  -- **Good blog post**

http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/  -- *some extra stuff here you get*